# Cookie problem after updating to 2.4.4-p2 (page not loading)

Tags: magento2.4, cookie

After updating from 2.3.5 to 2.4.4-p2 I am getting an error when the frontend loads. This is how it looks, when I load the frontend: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1liN.png

The admin works just fine and there are no errors during cimpilation, upgrade or deployment. Any idea how to solve this? The error in the logs is: `Error: Call to a member function getCookieSecure() on null in /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/js/cookie.phtml:21`

The code on line 21 is this:

```
"secure": <?= $block->getSessionConfig()->getCookieSecure() ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
```

It seems getSessionConfig returns null.

Running on PHP 8.1

Ideas?

Comment: Some checks you can do: is your custom theme overriding that template? do you have some third party module which could be involved here? try disabling one by one

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your layout you (or an extension) have the following definition:

```xml
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml"/>
```

However, since Magento `2.4.4` (or maybe even sooner) this needs to be updated to

```xml
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="session_config" xsi:type="object">Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\SessionConfig</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

otherwise `$block->getSessionConfig()` in the `cookie.phtml` template will be `null`.

Comment: This is the fix! In my case it was in the child theme I created in app/design